# C# Setting a public property in another class

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a a class below.
The StartDispensing method will run on a continuous loop until the public properties of that class change.

My question is how to I set those properties from another class.

Code for class1 below.

```
 using Abp.Dependency;
using Abp.Reflection.Extensions;
using Erx.Middleware.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Erx.Middleware.TCPCommunicator.Executer
{
    public class IndexerDispenserExecuter : ITransientDependency
    {
        private readonly Log _log;
        private readonly IConfigurationRoot _appConfiguration;            
        public bool IsToteWaiting { get; set; } = false;
        public bool IsIndexerFull { get; set; } = true;

        public IndexerDispenserExecuter(Log log)
        {
            _log = log;
            _appConfiguration = AppConfigurations.Get(
              typeof(TcpCommunicatorModule).GetAssembly().GetDirectoryPathOrNull()
          );
        }

        public void Run()
        {
          
            new Thread(() =>
            {
                Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground = true;
                StartDispensing();
            }).Start();

        }

        private void StartDispensing()
        {
            try
            {
                while (true)
                {
                   if (IsIndexerFull && IsToteWaiting) //NEED TO be able to set these variables from anywhere in the application
                    {
                        _log.Write("Do Something");
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                _log.Write("Server Error : " + e.ToString());
            }
        }    

    }

}
```

I want to change the public property IsToteWaiting from another class in another file.
When I change the value of the IsToteWaiting property to true I expect to hit the do something line.

```
    using Abp.Dependency;
using Abp.Events.Bus;
using Abp.Reflection.Extensions;
using Erx.Middleware.Configuration;
using Erx.Middleware.TCPCommunicator.Domain;
using Erx.Middleware.TCPCommunicator.Executer; // Reference to class
using Erx.Middleware.TCPCommunicator.Messages;
using Erx.Middleware.TCPCommunicator.Models;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Erx.Middleware.TCPCommunicator.Handlers
{
    public class MessageHandler : ITransientDependency
    {
        private readonly Log _log;
        private readonly IConfigurationRoot _appConfiguration;
        TcpPLCClientExecuter _tcpPLCClientExecuter;
        IndexerDispenserExecuter _indexerDispenserExecuter; //Instantiate Class
        PLCMessages _PlcMessages;
        WorkItemManager _workItemManager;
        public IEventBus EventBus { get; set; }


        public MessageHandler(
            Log log, TcpPLCClientExecuter tcpPLCClientExecuter, PLCMessages PlcMessages, WorkItemManager workItemManager, IndexerDispenserExecuter indexerDispenserExecuter)
        {
            _log = log;
            _tcpPLCClientExecuter = tcpPLCClientExecuter;
            _PlcMessages = PlcMessages;
            _workItemManager = workItemManager;
            _indexerDispenserExecuter = indexerDispenserExecuter; //Assign Class
            EventBus = NullEventBus.Instance;
            _appConfiguration = AppConfigurations.Get(
              typeof(TcpCommunicatorModule).GetAssembly().GetDirectoryPathOrNull()
          );
        }
        public string ValidateMessage(string message)
        {
            var result = "OK";
            return result;
        }


        public async Task HandleMessages(string message)
        {           
           _indexerDispenserExecuter.IsToteWaiting = true;
        }

    }


}
```

Updated Working solution

```
using Abp.Dependency;
using Abp.Domain.Uow;
using Abp.Reflection.Extensions;
using Abp.Threading.BackgroundWorkers;
using Abp.Threading.Timers;
using Erx.Middleware.Configuration;
using Erx.Middleware.TCPCommunicator;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;

public class DispenseIndexHandler : PeriodicBackgroundWorkerBase, ISingletonDependency
{
    private readonly Log _log;
    private readonly IConfigurationRoot _appConfiguration;
    public bool IsToteWaiting { get; set; } = false;

    public DispenseIndexHandler(AbpTimer timer, Log log)
        : base(timer)
    {
        _log = log;
        Timer.Period = 5000; //5 seconds (good for tests, but normally will be more)
        _appConfiguration = AppConfigurations.Get(
             typeof(TcpCommunicatorModule).GetAssembly().GetDirectoryPathOrNull()
         );
    }

    [UnitOfWork]
    protected override void DoWork()
    {
        if (IsToteWaiting)
        { 
            _log.Write("ToteWaiting for dispense"); 
        }

    }

    private void Dispense()
    {

    }

    private void MoveForWard()
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: 1. That file has to be in the same solution. 2. If it is, and the code that you presented above is a part of a DLL, you will just have to write `using Erx.Middleware.TCPCommunicator.Executer` at the top of that file and make sure that this DLL is present in the project solution references. 3. Just create an instance of that class and change the value of the boolean.

Comment: Hi There I did exactly that. But its not changing the value or stepping into that code method. I will show full source code of second class.

Comment: You are not calling HandleMessages()....

Comment: Handle Messages is being executed Its not updating the value of The property. Does it have something to do with the facts that its looping continuosly and is a timeing issues

Comment: HandleMessages() is being called from another class. That is not the issues the issue is the property assignment is not working.

Comment: Are you sure the loop and the property are on the same *instance* of the `IndexerDispenserExecuter` class? And: `ManualResetEvent` would probably be a better fit than a bool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your problem is changing the property from **"another thread"** not **"another class"**. Since another class just works because the class and the properties are public with public setters.

You need to make the properties have a backing field with [volatile keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/volatile).
Example:

```
private volatile bool _isToteWaiting = false;
public bool IsToteWaiting
{
    get
    { 
        return _isToteWaiting;
    }
    set
    {
        _isToteWaiting = value;
    }
}
```

Because it looks without volatile, your code can be optimized to read the property once instead of

Comment: Definitely on to something here it must be a threading issues as I can do this normally when not using threading

Comment: Then as Klaus said earlier in a comment, better use Manual Reset Event.

Comment: I Tried the volatile keyword but it still doesn't change the property value. Within the thread.

Comment: Just to let you know I resolved it using ABP background worker. As I am using it as my base architecture.

Answer (score 0):

to set a public property of a class (A) from another class (B):

1. instantiate a new instance of the class (B) inside a method of class (A). Or get it from somewhere else...
2. set the property

code:

```
class ClassA
{
    private void initClassB(myType myValue)
    { 
        ClassB MyClassB = new ClassB();
        MyClassB.MyProperty = myValue;
    }
 }
```

Comment: But this is what the OP is doing already: `_indexerDispenserExecuter.IsToteWaiting = true;`

Comment: "My question is how to I set those properties from another class."